# Create new Tenant based on existed. Import / Export operation in FoxIDs

Tags: foxids

Dear community could you please help me with question:
Is there any way to create tenant (in [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs)) as copy of another one or import/export settings for tenant?

We have more than 20 tenants and we want to simplify the tenant creating process.

Thanks a lot for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FoxIDs Control API](https://www.foxids.com/docs/control#foxids-control-api) to export and import all elements in a tenant including creating the new tenant. But you need to code a program to handle the export / import process.

As example code you can look at the [sample seed tool](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/tree/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool) which use the Control API to [create down-parties and up-parties in a track](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/blob/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool/Logic/SampleSeedLogic.cs).

The sample seed tool uses an autogenerated [service access](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/tree/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool/ServiceAccess) proxy [enabled](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/blob/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool.csproj#L9) and [configured in the .csproj](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs.Samples/blob/master/tools/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool/FoxIDs.SampleSeedTool.csproj#L42) file.

You can finde an online Swagger (OpenApi) at: https://control.foxids.com/api/swagger/v1/swagger.json.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will help me a lot!